# Checkboxes in map not updating on array update after refactor to react hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I converted a class component into a function component using hooks. Currently, I'm struggling to figure out why the checkboxes within this map is not updating with checked value, despite the onChange handler firing, and updating the array as necessary. (The onSubmit also works, and updates the value within the DB properly).

```
import {
  Container,
  Typography,
  Grid,
  Checkbox,
  FormControlLabel,
  Button
} from "@material-ui/core";
import Select from "react-select";
import localeSelect from "../services/localeSelect";
import {
  linkCharactersToGame,
  characterLinked,
  linkCharacters
} from "../data/locales";
import dbLocale from "../services/dbLocale";
import { LanguageContext } from "../contexts/LanguageContext";
import { UserContext } from "../contexts/UserContext";
import { GameContext } from "../contexts/GameContext";
import { CharacterContext } from "../contexts/CharacterContext";
import { Redirect } from "react-router-dom";

export default function LinkCharacter() {
  const { language } = useContext(LanguageContext);
  const { user } = useContext(UserContext);
  const { games, loading, error, success, connectCharacters } = useContext(
    GameContext
  );
  const { characters } = useContext(CharacterContext);
  const [game, setGame] = useState("");
  const [selectedCharacters, setSelectedCharacters] = useState([]);
  if (!user) {
    return <Redirect to="/" />;
  }
  return (
    <section className="link-character">
      <Container maxWidth="sm">
        <Typography variant="h5">
          {localeSelect(language, linkCharactersToGame)}
        </Typography>
        {error && (
          <p className="error">
            <span>Error:</span> {error}
          </p>
        )}
        {success && <p>{localeSelect(language, characterLinked)}</p>}
        <Select
          options={games.map(game => {
            return {
              label: dbLocale(language, game),
              value: game._id
            };
          })}
          onChange={e => {
            setGame(e.value);
            const selected = [];
            const index = games.findIndex(x => x._id === e.value);
            games[index].characters.forEach(character => {
              selected.push(character._id);
            });
            setSelectedCharacters(selected);
          }}
        />
      </Container>
      <Container maxWidth="md">
        {game !== "" && (
          <>
            <Grid container spacing={2}>
              {characters.map((character, index) => {
                return (
                  <Grid item key={index} md={3} sm={4} xs={6}>
                    <FormControlLabel
                      control={
                        <Checkbox
                          value={character._id}
                          onChange={e => {
                            const index = selectedCharacters.indexOf(
                              e.target.value
                            );
                            if (index === -1) {
                              selectedCharacters.push(e.target.value);
                            } else {
                              selectedCharacters.splice(index, 1);
                            }
                          }}
                          color="primary"
                          checked={
                            selectedCharacters.indexOf(character._id) !== -1
                          }
                        />
                      }
                      label={dbLocale(language, character)}
                    />
                  </Grid>
                );
              })}
            </Grid>
            <Button
              variant="contained"
              color="primary"
              onClick={e => {
                e.preventDefault();
                connectCharacters(game, selectedCharacters);
              }}
            >
              {localeSelect(language, linkCharacters)}
            </Button>
          </>
        )}
      </Container>
    </section>
  );
}
```

I feel like there's something I'm missing within Hooks (or there's some sort of issue with Hooks handling something like this). I have been searching and asking around and no one else has been able to figure out this issue as well.

Comment: can you change `e.value` to `e.target.value`

Comment: @iamhuynq in addition to having nothing to do with the checkbox issue, `value` resides on `e` in react-select, not `e.target`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `state` returned by `[state, setState] = useState([])` is something that you should only be ***reading*** from. If you modify it, React won't know that the data has changed and that it needs to re-render. When you need to modify data, you have to use `setState`, or in your case `setSelectedCharacters`.

Also, modifying the data by reference might lead to unpredictable results if the array is read elsewhere, later on.

In addition to that, if you give the same value to `setState`, that the hook returned you in `state`, React will skip the update entirely. It is not a problem when using numbers or strings, but it becomes one when you use arrays, because the reference (the value React uses to tell if there is a difference) can be the same, when the content might have changed. So you **must** pass a new array to `setState`.

With that in mind, your `onChange` function could look like:

```js
onChange={e => {
  const index = selectedCharacters.indexOf(
    e.target.value
  );
  if (index === -1) {
    // creating a new array with [], so the original one stays intact
    setSelectedCharacters([...selectedCharacters, e.target.value]);
  } else {
    // Array.filter also creates new array
    setSelectedCharacters(selectedCharacters.filter((char, i) => i !== index));
  }
}}
```

Doc is here https://en.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usestate

Comment: This did not solve the issue, the checkbox still doesn't update upon clicking it.

Comment: @MissingPersonFGC Would it be possible for you to provide a reduced example so I can play with it ?

Comment: Sorry, I should've mentioned this sooner, but I revisited this later and figured out I was making mistakes in spreading adding the value to the array (I put e.target.value outside of the array after the spread). Once I rewrote it, this solution worked.